# django rest framework save(using='database') not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view -

```
class DeployResourceFilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        resname = self.request.GET.get('name')
        queryset = Resmst.objects.using('Admiral').filter(resmst_name=resname)
        serializer = ResourceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        if queryset:
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            raise Http404

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ResourceSerializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(using='Admiral')
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The GET works fine and is pulling the data from the 'Admiral' database but as soon as I do a post from the webpage it returns an error that the table doesn't exist because it's trying to save to the 'default' database.  I'm not sure why it's doing this because I'm explicitly saving to the specific database.  Here's the traceback -

I'll note here that the sqlite3 database is the default database.  The 'Admiral' database is an sql server database.  Therefore I know the using='Admiral' is not working.

```
Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  397.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Tidal\API\views.py" in post
  311.         if serializer.is_valid():
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in is_valid
  553.         return not self.errors
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in errors
  535.                         ret.append(self.from_native(item, None))
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in from_native
  996.         instance = super(ModelSerializer, self).from_native(data, files)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in from_native
  368.             attrs = self.restore_fields(data, files)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in restore_fields
  283.                 field.field_from_native(data, files, field_name, reverted_data)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py" in field_from_native
  189.             into[(self.source or field_name)] = self.from_native(value)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py" in from_native
  228.             return self.queryset.get(pk=data)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  304.         num = len(clone)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  77.         self._fetch_all()
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  857.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  713.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  451.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /deploy/resource/
Exception Value: no such table: owner
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to work around this by create routers.  I made a specific router referencing this 'Admiral' db and then assigned it to the app 'API'.

settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'routers.DefaultRouter', 'routers.AdmiralRouter', 'routers.TIDALRouter' ]
```

routers.py

```
class TIDALRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'API':
            return 'Admiral'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to Admiral.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'API':
            return 'Admiral'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'API' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'API':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'Admiral'
        database.
        """
        if db == 'Admiral':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'API'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'API':
            return False
        return None
```